# sqlite3 C user defined function not being called

Tags: c, sqlite, user-defined-functions, raspberry-pi3, udf

first post here! This site has been of paramount help on a huge number of previous tech matters.
Thanks for your hard work, collectively spoken.

And now coming to my problem.

I'd like to write a C sqlite3 UDF (User Defined Function).
Assume the function name is "myFunc".

I work on a Raspberry PI 3B - Raspbian default (distro up-to-date).

test_table has the following schema:

```
create table test_table (
  a           integer,
  b           integer
);
```

The mini-program (to test the approach) opens the DB and installs the function.
Then waits indefinitely for trigger events.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static void myFuncBody(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    printf("myFunc fired!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    sqlite3 *db_handler;
    char *errMsg;
    int error;

    error = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db_handler);
    if (error)
    {
        printf("Error opening the DB.\n");
        exit(-2);
    }

    error = sqlite3_create_function(
        db_handler,
        "myFunc",
        0,
        SQLITE_UTF8,
        NULL,
        myFuncBody,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    if (error != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("Error creating the function.\n");
    }

    for (;;);

    return 0;
}
```

I then open separately test.db on the sqlite3 console:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db

$ sqlite> select myFunc();
Error: no such function: myFunc
```

I think myFunc should be visible but this seems not to be the case.

I could also create a trigger but the result obviously does not change.

```
$ sqlite>  create trigger trigger1 after insert on test_table begin select myFunc(); end;

$ sqlite> insert into test_table values(-100, -150);
Error: no such function: myFunc
```

My aim is simply to be notified about an insertion on test_table.

Is something basically wrong with my approach?

Any help would be much approciated.

Regards,
mopyot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding here:

A newly defined C-function is only defined in the context of the handle (`db_handler` in your case) where it was added. It is not future part of the database file `test.db`.

So if you do a

```
sqlite3_exec(db_handler, "select myFunc()", ...);
```

after your call to `sqlite3_create_function()` it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Understood, tried and verified. So is there a way to actually be notified about insertions performed by other actors?

Comment: @mopyot If you are talking about seperate processes: there is no mechanism provided by the sqlite3-engine, you will have to use another means of interprocess-communication to achieve this.